# Why is my bezier curve implementation biased?

Tags: c++, bezier

I want to render bezier curves in C++, so I started implementing it myself. For now, it doesn't have to be very efficient. My code somehow produces a near result, but those curves aren't accurate. (`dvec2` is a vector of two double values.)

```
list<dvec2> bezier(list<dvec2> const &points, int resolution)
{
    list<dvec2> samples;
    double step = 1.0 / resolution;
    for (double time = 0.0; time <= 1.0; time += step) {
        list<dvec2> sliders = points;
        while (sliders.size() > 1)
            sliders = slide(sliders, time);
        samples.push_back(sliders.front());
    }
    return samples;
}

list<dvec2> slide(list<dvec2> const &points, double time)
{
    list<dvec2> result;
    auto current = points.begin();
    dvec2 last = *current;
    for (++current; current != points.end(); ++current)
        result.push_back(last * time + *current * (1.0 - time));
    return result;
}
```

Currently, I create n-1 points from a curve by interpolating the first with the second, the second with the third, and so on, based on time t. Then, I reduce this new set of points again by the same algorithm, until I'm left with one point that I can draw. I think the approach should work.

On rendered image, you can see the algorithms outcome on several rendered curves.

[image: rendering looks similar to bezier curves]

For example, in the bottom left of the image, the two opposing curves should by symmetrical I think. Mine are biased by the direction. Moreover, those fully enclosed curves should at least draw a point in the center for t=0.5. What is causing this?

Comment: The fact that you use non-const references is very irritating and confused me a lot when reading your code. I was sure you are mutating the lists in the functions, but in fact you don't... And is there a reason why you use lists instead of vectors? Lists are slower in almost every use case scenario.

Comment: @leemes Thanks for the advice, I'll add them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach should work. You made a little oversight: Within `slide()`, you don't update `last` in your loop.

Try:

```
for (++current; current != points.end(); ++current) {
    result.push_back(last * time + *current * (1.0 - time));
    last = *current; // <--
}
```

---

Note that a different interpretation of bezier curves can be given by taking the sum of these products:

> (Source: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Terminology))
>
> Some terminology is associated with these parametric curves. We have
>
> [image: \mathbf{B}(t) = \sum_{i=0}^n b_{i, n}(t)\mathbf{P}_i,\quad t \in [0, 1]]
>
> where the polynomials
>
> [image: b_{i,n}(t) = {n\choose i} t^i (1 - t)^{n - i},\quad i = 0, \ldots, n]
>
> are known as Bernstein basis polynomials of degree *n*.

Here, you need (precomputed) binomial coefficients, and by using the `std::pow` function you end up with a single loop instead of two nested ones (considering *n* to be limited by a constant in practice, to make precomputation possible).

Comment: Thank you, it's working now. Yes, I'll optimize that later, because currently, I don't know how to compute the coefficients.

Comment: @danijar Do you want to support bezier curves of an arbitrary number of control points? If you can restrict them (let's say to 20), I suggest a precomputed table of binomial coefficients. Write the binomial coefficient function as a `constexpr` function, so it's computed during compile time. If you don't want to restrict them, you can do the following trick: if there are more points (`n`), reduce every next `20` of them to get a list of `n-20` points. Then repeat. So in the end it's still two loops but unlikely to need more than one iteration on the outer loop. I hope this explanation helped.

Comment: Ahh, okay I see. The coefficients are easy then. I just need curves with up to 8 points, so that's no problem. How would I include the time in the computation?

Comment: Ah sorry, the term `bi,n(t)` in the formula isn't *just* the coefficients, but a function using them and the time. It's explained here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Terminology -- Maybe in the end it's not better than your step-wise reduction since it uses power: `bi,n(t) = B(n,i) * t^i * (1-t)^(n-i)`. where `B(n,i)` are the coefficients, and `^` denotes power.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your explanation, I understand the formula now. However, the current implementation is fast enough for my needs.

Comment: it's also generally much faster to just write out the binomial terms as an array since you rarely ever use anything other than 2-4th order curves, for which the coefficients are [1,2,1], [1,3,3,1] and [1,4,6,4,1] respectively.